# Access SQL - SUM(IIF... vs IIF(SUM... performance implication

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have looked online but have been unable to find information about this.

I am just wondering which of the following SQL queries would execute most quickly for a large dataset in MS Access:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF([Field] = 0, null, [Field])) AS SumField
FROM tbl1
```

or

```
SELECT IIF(SUM([Field]) = 0, null, Sum([Field])) AS SumField
FROM tbl1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two do different things.  The first adds numbers that are not zero.  The result can be zero (for instance, if the values are -1 and 1).  The second can never by zero.

In any case, the difference in performance is going to be minimal.  There is perhaps a wee amount of overhead for calculating the `IFF()` for every row, but the effort to do the aggregation should swamp that.  And, a wee amount of overhead for calculating the `SUM()` twice in the second case.

The more important issue is getting the logic correct.  Also, the first is equivalent to:

```
SELECT SUM([Field]) as sumField
FROM tbl;
```

Comment: The second case won't have any overhead for 2 calls, as Access caches function results and returns the same result if the same input parameters are specified (this is why dummy input variables are sometimes used).

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me to understand the logic properly. I am effectively doing this as my actual query divides another value by the result of the above and I am trying to avoid div/0 errors (without having to check the divisor separately) I will go with the second one so it can never be zero

Answer (score 1):

To get a definitive answer, you would need to find some documentation stating whether or not that `sum` will be executed twice in your second script or not.

Failing that, you can simply take the safe course of action, which is your first query that will guarantee the `sum` is only calculated the once.